# How do I debug Go dependency packages?

Tags: go

Say my Go project depends on package `example.com/foo`.  I am using Go `1.12`, so the dependency is automatically pulled in by Go modules. The dependency seems to have a bug, so I want to add logs in the source code.

I can find the source code of on GitHub but I don't know how to make it as part of my project for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First fetch all the dependency packages into the `vendor` folder.

```
go mod vendor
```

Then, change the source code in that and build your project by specifying to look into `vendor` folder.

```
go build -mod=vendor
```

or

```
go run -mod=vendor myapp.go
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I specify only the desired package? no others.

Comment: You don't need to. Vendor folder will contain all packages but you will only change the one you want to debug.

Comment: It worked perfectly. After debugging, I can simply delete the vendor/ folder, right?

Comment: Correct, delete the vendor folder and build/run your project as usual (i.e. just `go build` or `go run`).

Comment: Should that be `go run -mod=vendor myapp.go`? (you have `mode`). It worked for me on go 1.17.1.

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: According to `go help build`, *By default, if a vendor directory is present and the go version in go.mod is 1.14 or higher, the go command acts as if -mod=vendor were set.*

Answer (score 14):

You can use [replace directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive):

```
replace example.com/original/import/path => /your/forked/import/path
```

Answer (score 8):

Go module fetches packages into `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` you can change the source code there or using the vendor option of go mod to pull the packages into vendor folder and then start coding there.