# How to debug a Go function returning multiple values in IntelliJ?

Tags: go, intellij-idea

Suppose we are debugging some Go code, and somewhere in an external dependency we encounter this line:

```
return json.Marshal(foo)
```

We want to set a breakpoint and use IntelliJ's "Evaluate Expression" to inspect the JSON being produced. However, this doesn't work:

- If we evaluate the expression `json.Marshal(foo)`, we only get to see the byte array.
- Evaluating `string(json.Marshal(foo))` doesn't work because `json.Marshal` returns two values, the byte array and an error.
- There is no way in Go to access one of the return values directly.

So how can I use "Evaluate Expression" to achieve my goal of just printing the produced JSON string when I'm not able to change the underlying source code?

Comment: The "byte array"[sic] (it's actually a byte slice) _is_ the JSON.

Comment: As a human, I don't speak fluent byte slice, though, and I would much rather view it as a proper string. It's also merely an example, the question generalizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can print the returned bytes as a string

```golang
bytes, err := json.Marshal(foo)
// check error here
fmt.Println(string(bytes))
```

### update based on comments

You can't change the byte slice in the debugger to a string without changing the source code.

Comment: No, I can't, because for this I need to change the source code, which I cannot do. I only have the "Evaluate Expression" at my disposal.

Comment: @IngoBürk How is it that you're able to debug a Go program, but not have access to the source code? That is a truly exceptional situation.

Comment: I have access to the source code (since I'm debugging it), but it is an external dependency, not my project.

Comment: Well then, you can change the external dependency during debugging with no problem. This is well documented both on SO, and on Google at large.

Comment: Here are some related questions for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56818094/13860 https://stackoverflow.com/q/58736604/13860

Comment: If I change the dependency's code during debugging, I need to carefully make sure to undo all changes, or re-install the dependencies again, though. This can't possibly be "the" way of simply debugging something(?)

Comment: There is never "the" way. There are simply "ways".  Use a way that works for you.  If you're concerned about making the change permanent: Don't commit it. That's usually pretty easy. Especially if you add `vendor` to `.gitignore`, for example. Then you _can't_ commit it, even by accident.

Comment: Beyond that, maybe IntelliJ, or some other IDE/debugger, has an option to display a byte slice as a string.  But that's far enough beyond Go itself, that I don't have experience in that area to help. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: The entire point of "Evaluate Expression" in IntelliJ is to not modify the source code for the purpose of debugging what's there. This is a ridiculous limitation in Go; anyway, it isn't your making, and I appreciate your time, but perhaps the answer to my question is rather "It's not possible", sad as that might be.

Comment: @IngoBürk Well, you are successfully evaluating the expression. So I don't see any limitation in Go at all.  You just seem to be unhappy with the way IntelliJ displays that info. So it seems to be a limitation in IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes, arguably it is a limitation of IntelliJ, but Go doesn't help here by having no "inline" way of accessing only one of the returned values. A debugging idiom that _requires_ changing the source code _is_ a limitation (IMO).

Comment: if you get the byte slice in your debugger just copy paste it and convert it to string somewhere else there are many tools that can convert byte slices to strings for you. also if you have no control over the source code why are you debugging it?

Comment: I'm debugging it because I'm investigating an issue, and possibly I will need to raise a bug against that dependency. Since I need to look at this expression called in a loop some few dozens of times, copy-pasting it every single time would be seriously uncomfortable.

Comment: in that case you should fork the dependency and make the changes you need to debug it

Comment: I realize that this is a possibility, but short of using gdb in C that has to be the worst developer experience for debugging something I've encountered. But let's not beat a dead horse here, if you would like to change / extend your answer to saying that what I am looking to do isn't possible I'll (semi-)happily accept it.

Comment: added an update that says you can't get a string without changing the source code